# Oracle delete query taking long time to delete the records from the table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Query:
`Delete from test_table;`    (i am using this delete command in Procedure to perform daily)

This table contains 2 column name like scenario_id, item_id, these 2 column are composite primary key. So Each scenario_id will have 2 millions item_id, How to delete this table quicky.

Comment: Try `truncate` table command, however `truncate` is DDL command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to delete the table might be `DROP TABLE test_table` command, and recreate the table using `CREATE TABLE...` command. `DROP TABLE...` will drop the table immediately. Well, actually it will move the table into recyclebin. You should `PURGE RECYCLEBIN` if want to completely remove the table.

Other way to delete the data in the table is to use `TRUNCATE TABLE...`. This is a little slower than `DROP TABLE...`, however, much faster than `DELETE FROM...`. Since there's no way to rollback the data after you truncate the table, you should be careful when you use `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

Comment: Is there any other way to delete the records without dropping the table. Also i am using Procedure to perform this delete action

Comment: @user2767714 drop and recreate is the fastest way. Other way is to `truncate table` as I mentioned in the answer. You can execute those command by using `execute immediate ...` in the procedure.

Comment: I am using below query. Its working fine.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test IS
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'truncate table test_table';
END test;
/

BEGIN
   test();
END;
/

Answer (score 0):

- Check if there are any Foreign keys pointing onto this table. If they are, there MUST be indexes on these referring columns. Otherwise maintenance of the referential integrity will take ages
- (Transactional) Delete on Oracle is slow by nature. Simple because of deleted data must be copied into UNDO tablespace, REDO logs and also archived REDO logs. This is the way how Oracle protects your data.
- If our are deleting more than 50% of data, it is much faster when you simply `create new table as select * from old_table where ...` and then drop the new old one and rename new to old.
- You can achieve similar goal by `exchanging` partitions in the partitioned table.
- Or you can simply drop table's partitions if your table is partitioned wisely